# "The only right something" in German

Tags: phrase

How do we say the phrase like *the only right decision* in German? Is it like

> der alleinige richtige Entscheid"?

It doesn't sound very well for me. Do we really say *alleinige richtige* or we can merge these two words into one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Der Entscheid* would be a helveticism. Outside Switzerland, most speakers prefer *die Entscheidung*.

Possible translations for *only* in this context are *alleinig+* or *allein+* and, preferably, *einzig+*. Two inflections are possible for all of them, depending on whether it’s considered an adverb that qualifies just the adjective *richtig+* or an adjective for *richtige Entscheidung*. As an adverb it would not use any inflection suffix and as an adjective it would have to agree with case, number and gender of *Entscheidung* (NomSgFem), like *richtige* does. Although they can be encountered used differently, I would recommend to restrict *allein* to adverbial use and *alleinig* to adjective use.

Adverb:

> - *die einzig richtige Entscheidung, der einzig richtigen …*
> - *die allein richtige Entscheidung, der allein richtigen …*

Adjective:

> - *die einzige richtige Entscheidung, der einzigen richtigen …*
> - *die alleinige richtige Entscheidung, der alleinigen richtigen …*